# $vuetify.goTo('#foo') not working on another router page

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I try to smooth scroll using the function: goTo("#how") provided by Vuetify. It worked fine but when I go to a different router page it gives an error.

[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "Error: Target element "#how" not found."

In my knowledge, it means that the target element does not exist.

I tried changing goTo("/#how"), goTo("/how") but it seems to be of no hope.

```
//App.vue where the header, footer of my app exist and the button that calls the function: goTo() 
<v-btn @click="() => this.$vuetify.goTo('#how')">How it Works</v-btn>
```

```
//The section where the page should scroll when the button is clicked
<section id="how">
</section>
```

```
//the goTo scroll function provided by Vuetify
scrollBehavior: (to, from, savedPosition) => {
  let scrollTo = 0

  if (to.hash) {
      scrollTo = to.hash
  } else if (savedPosition) {
      scrollTo = savedPosition.y
  }

  return goTo(scrollTo)
}
```

I expect it when on another route page and the button is clicked, it should scroll smoothly to the section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have found a solution to my problem. It may not be the cleanest way but it works.

My solution is to put a conditional statement for the buttons.

```
//First check if the current route is on landing page (or wherever your #foo is) then set the click function for it.
<v-btn v-if='this.$route.path == "/"' color="white" @click="() => this.$vuetify.goTo('#foo')" flat>How it Works</v-btn>

//If route.path is not at "/" then we call the router push to redirect first to Landing and then scroll.
<v-btn v-else color="white" @click="() => this.$router.push('/#foo')" flat>How it Works</v-btn>
```